# fill a grid with selected rows of another grid

Tags: c#, xaml, datagrid, itemssource, selectionchanged

Code is C# and the datagrid is in XAML.  The problem here is that we have one grid with rows of articles. When we select a row, this row must be immediately added to a second grid.  We use for this a list, which is defined on a higher level.  When we select one row, this works fine. When we select another row, this row not appears in the second grid. 
However: with debugging we see that after the first selection the count of the itemsource = 1 and the count of the listgrid2 = 1.

After the second selection the count of the itemsoucre = 2 and the count of listgrid2 = 2.

But there are never filled up more than one row in the second grid..
Is there anyone familiar with this problem?  Thanx in advance

```
int rijindex = grid1.SelectedIndex;
if (rijindex != -1)
{
    int artnrGrid2 = listartb2[rijindex].artbnr;
    string artnaamGrid2 = listartb2[rijindex].artbnaam;

    dbGrid2 x = new dbGrid2('X', artnrGrid2, artnaamGrid2);
    listgrid2.Add(x);
    grid2.ItemsSource = listgrid2;
```

Comment: What is the definition of `listgrid2`? Does it implement property change, or is it a dependency property?

Comment: private List<dbGrid2> listgrid2 = new List<dbGrid2>();

this is the definition of listgrid2.

dbGrid2 is a class with 3 propertys (char, int, string) with getters and setters.

Comment: Problem is solved now. I had to set grid2.ItemsSource = null before fill the grid

Comment: You don't have to nullify the source if you can make `listgrid2` to be `ObservableCollection<dbGrid2>`. The problem is that right now you don't have notification when the list is changed, so `ItemsSource` is not updating.